# PHP array merge & erase values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge a multi-dimentional array so that after merging the new values will be equal to 0 instead of the original value.

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
  '2009-05-12' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2010-12-07' => string '8' (length=1)
  '2010-12-02' => string '23' (length=2)
  '2010-11-11' => string '16' (length=2)
  '2010-09-01' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2010-08-24' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2010-06-30' => string '1' (length=1)
  ), 1 => array(
  '2010-09-08' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2011-11-28' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2011-09-28' => string '3' (length=1)
  '2011-09-21' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2012-04-10' => string '21' (length=2)
  '2012-04-02' => string '12' (length=2)
  ), 2 => array(
  '2010-12-15' => string '12' (length=2)
  '2010-12-08' => string '12' (length=2)
  '2010-11-28' => string '12' (length=2)
  '2010-06-30' => string '12' (length=2)
  '2010-05-04' => string '1' (length=1)
  '2011-12-21' => string '9' (length=1)
  '2012-01-05' => string '23' (length=2)
  ), 3 => array(
  '2010-12-14' => string '2' (length=1)
  '2010-12-10' => string '4' (length=1)
  '2010-11-29' => string '4' (length=1)
  '2011-10-04' => string '7' (length=1)
  '2011-09-27' => string '11' (length=2)
  '2012-01-06' => string '1' (length=1)
  )
);
```

What I succeeded to do was to create a loop that was merging elements in the array:

```
foreach($data as $index => $date){
    foreach($data as $index2 => $date2)
        $data[$index] = array_merge($data[$index2], $data[$index]);
}
```

The above script outputs almost the correct result, but the merged values should be equal to 0 and not to the original value.

The output of the above script merges each of the nested arrays so that it contains values of the all remaining nested arrays.

The output should be:

```
$data = array(
0 => array(
'2009-05-12' => string '1' (length=1)
'2010-12-07' => string '8' (length=1)
'2010-12-02' => string '23' (length=2)
'2010-11-11' => string '16' (length=2)
'2010-09-01' => string '1' (length=1)
'2010-08-24' => string '1' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '1' (length=1)
'2010-09-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-11-28' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-28' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-15' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-05-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-12-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-05' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-14' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-29' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-10-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-27' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-06' => string '0' (length=1)
), 1 => array(
'2009-05-12' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-07' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-11' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-01' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-08-24' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-08' => string '1' (length=1)
'2011-11-28' => string '1' (length=1)
'2011-09-28' => string '3' (length=1)
'2011-09-21' => string '1' (length=1)
'2012-04-10' => string '21' (length=2)
'2012-04-02' => string '12' (length=2)
'2010-12-15' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-05-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-12-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-05' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-14' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-29' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-10-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-27' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-06' => string '0' (length=1)
), 2 => array(
'2009-05-12' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-07' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-11' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-01' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-08-24' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-28' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-15' => string '12' (length=2)
'2010-12-08' => string '12' (length=2)
'2010-11-28' => string '12' (length=2)
'2010-06-30' => string '12' (length=2)
'2010-05-04' => string '1' (length=1)
'2011-12-21' => string '9' (length=1)
'2012-01-05' => string '23' (length=2)
'2010-12-14' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-29' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-10-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-27' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-06' => string '0' (length=1)
), 3 => array(
'2009-05-12' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-07' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-11' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-01' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-08-24' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-09-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-28' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-09-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-10' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-04-02' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-15' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-12-08' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-11-28' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-06-30' => string '0' (length=1)
'2010-05-04' => string '0' (length=1)
'2011-12-21' => string '0' (length=1)
'2012-01-05' => string '0' (length=2)
'2010-12-14' => string '2' (length=1)
'2010-12-10' => string '4' (length=1)
'2010-11-29' => string '4' (length=1)
'2011-10-04' => string '7' (length=1)
'2011-09-27' => string '11' (length=2)
'2012-01-06' => string '1' (length=1)
)
```

);

Comment: Can you just cycle through the resulting array and set all of the values to 0?

Comment: what do you mean by values should be equal to 0? Please show what you would like the output to be.

Comment: he wants to clear merged values, am i right?

Comment: @jdwire I dont think so, because in the loop the values are needed a couple of times.

Comment: I want to clear the merged values to `0`

Comment: then why merge it in the first place? like jdwire said, can't you just set all values to 0?

Comment: what would be another apporach to achieve the result I want then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use array_merge.

```
foreach($data as $index => $v){
    foreach($data as $data2){
       foreach($data2 as $date=> $val){
          if(!array_key_exist($date,$data[$index])){
            $data[$index][$date] = 0;
          }
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced the `in_array` part with `array_key_exist` and it works. Please change your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: There you go. My apologies. You could probably use !isset($data[$index][$date]) as well.